# Simple AngularJS routing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*Home* and *About* page have simple heading content which is not showing when running the page. Instead it is showing:

> Error: $injector:modulerr
>   Module Error".

How do I fix this?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        .when('/', {
         templateUrl : 'partial/home.html',
        })
        .when('/about', {
         templateUrl: 'partial/about.html',
        })
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'})
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
      <nav>
          <a href="#/">Home</a>
          <a href="#/about">About</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, you should use `$urlRouterProvider`

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Comment: this is also not working!! :( I am new to AngularJS so don't know what exactly wrong is with code.

Comment: If your application only contains the code that you showed in your first post, the issue could be that you haven't installed the node package of ng-route. Did you use yeoman to generate the project? In order to help you i need you to update a plnkr. I recommend you to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead of ngRoute [here is an simple example using ui-router](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVB5Jg?p=info)

Comment: Thanks Matho!! I was running my code just locally on a browser when i tried with local host, it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't run your code, I can see a syntax error.

EDIT: Actually you have two syntax errors, rather than missing out a '.', you've added two after $routeProvider.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider. //Two '.'s 
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'partial/home.html',

    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'partial/about.html',

    })
    //No '.' here
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'})
});
```

So replace the above with the '.', so the function chaining doesn't break.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'partial/home.html',

    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'partial/about.html',

    })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'})
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lee!! Yea that syntax is gone but still have Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error".